# How to calculate riser dimensions given cast material and cast dimensions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, casting

I tried to calculate the dimensions of a cylindrical riser with height and diameter being the same ,for casting  a steel cube,I tried using both Caine's and modulus method to solve it ,but every single time I am getting dimensions of the riser similar to that of my cast,which my instructor claims is wrong, can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your class question; but, when I worked in a foundry in the real world for a few years, gates and risers were designed by experience ( no computers then) . However , there are still matters like "hot tops" ( exothermic riser topping,) superheat ( adjusted for pattern complexity), length and thickness of thin sections, etc. Mold temperature and composition of the sand. That is; the same weight of steel may be poured at different temperatures depending on the pattern and other factors. Not considering differences caused by the alloy( very impressive to watch an aluminum bronze riser shrink down the center like small hole was drilled in it.).